# How to prevent elements from moving in Column after one's visibility is changed?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So, as it is in the title, I'm facing problem with preventing a group of elements from moving, when one of the elements, wrapped in Visibility, becomes visible/invisible. I am new to Flutter, so I couldn't neither solve the problem nor find the solution anywhere.

I created sample code and made 2 screenshots to show the problem more clearly.

**screenshots:**

[State 1, before the button is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AMGR.jpg)

[State 2, after the button is clicked (button clicked changes visibility of the text below)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBOj8.jpg)

**code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'MyApp',
        home: MyAppHome()
    );
  }
}

class MyAppHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppHomeState createState() => _MyAppHomeState();
}

class _MyAppHomeState extends State<MyAppHome> {
  bool isVisible = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: _buildStateWidget()
    );
  }

  Widget _buildStateWidget() {
    return Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Some text 1', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0)),
            SizedBox(
                width: 200.0,
                height: 200.0,
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      isVisible = !isVisible;
                    });
                  },
                )),
            Visibility(
                visible: isVisible,
                child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'Some text 2',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.favorite_border
                      )
                    ]
                )
            )
          ],
        )
    );
}
}
```

I understand, why it behaves like this, but I don't know how to fix that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could wrap your FAB and the widget below it with `Expanded`

Here's my solution:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(title: 'MyApp', home: MyAppHome());
  }
}

class MyAppHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppHomeState createState() => _MyAppHomeState();
}

class _MyAppHomeState extends State<MyAppHome> {
  bool isVisible = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: _buildStateWidget());
  }

  Widget _buildStateWidget() {
    return Center(
        child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Some text 1', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0)),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            height: 200.0,
            width: 200.0,
            child: FittedBox(
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    isVisible = !isVisible;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: Visibility(
                visible: isVisible,
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Some text 2',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  Icon(Icons.favorite_border)
                ])))
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

NOTE: I've changed the way you resize your FAB

Comment: Thanks, that almost made it. However, there is a problem that appeared after adding Expanded: both Texts and Button became aligned to the very top of the screen (just copied your code to test), while in my code everything's centered. Trying to deal with it right now

Comment: So, everything that I was able to reach is center the top `Text` and the `Button` by wrapping top `Text` into `Expanded` and then `Center`, and leaving `Button` as it is in `Expanded` in your code. I've tried a lot of things to center second `Text`, but failed